# How to install the new "Boost" dependency using the "AzerothCore Bash Dashboard" installation?

Tags: azerothcore

I have an AzerothCore Bash Dashboard installed version.

What should I do to install "Boost" as it seems to be required (from the announcement message on Discord dated May 24th 2021) going forward?

Does a simple

```
sudo apt-get  install boost
```

work? Or since I installed with the bash dashboard issuing a

```
git pull
```

followed by a

```
./acore.sh compiler build
```

Will take care of installing any missing dependencies?

Or should I run, instead, another time:

```
./acore.sh install-deps
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 on an AC bash dashboard setup:

```
sudo apt install libboost-all-dev
```

and I successfully managed to update my AC version to latest.

Tested both core compile and run.